Improving the model structure in a pix2pix image to image translation problem
I have a pix2pix image to image translation source code where my images (tensors) have the shape: 512 x 512 x 12 and my generator() looks like below:
def generator(gf_dim=20, input_c_dim=12, output_c_dim=12):
    inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[512, 512, input_c_dim])

    # Downsampling through the model
    down_stack = [
        conv2d(
            gf_dim, activation="leaky_relu", name="g_e1_conv"
        ),  # (bs, 256, 256, gf_dim)
        conv2d(
            gf_dim * 2, activation="leaky_relu", name="g_e2_conv"
        ),  # (bs, 128, 128, gf_dim*2)
        conv2d(
            gf_dim * 4, activation="leaky_relu", name="g_e3_conv"
        ),  # (bs, 64, 64, gf_dim*4)
        conv2d(
            gf_dim * 8, activation="leaky_relu", name="g_e4_conv"
        ),  # (bs, 32, 32, gf_dim*8)
        conv2d(
            gf_dim * 8, activation="leaky_relu", name="g_e5_conv"
        ),  # (bs, 16, 16, gf_dim*8)
    ]

    # Upsampling and establishing the skip connections
    up_stack = [
        deconv2d(
            gf_dim * 8, apply_dropout=True, name="g_d1"
        ),  # (bs, 32, 32, gf_dim*16)
        deconv2d(gf_dim * 4, name="g_d2"),  # (bs, 64, 64, gf_dim*8)
        deconv2d(gf_dim * 2, name="g_d3"),  # (bs, 128, 128, gf_dim*4)
        deconv2d(gf_dim, name="g_d4"),  # (bs, 256, 256, gf_dim*2)
    ]

    last = tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
        output_c_dim,
        4,
        strides=2,
        padding="same",
        activation="tanh",  # (bs, 512, 512, output_c_dim)
        name="g_d6",
    )

    x = inputs
    skips = []
    for down in down_stack:
        x = down(x)
        skips.append(x)

    skips = reversed(skips[:-1])
    for up, skip in zip(up_stack, skips):
        x = up(x)
        x = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([x, skip])

    x = last(x)

    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=x)

And my discriminator() is like below:
def discriminator(input_shape=(512, 512, 12)):
    initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0.0, 0.02)

    inp = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape, name="input_image")

    x = inp

    down1 = downsample(64, 4, False)(x)  # (bs, 256, 256, 64)
    down2 = downsample(128, 4)(down1)  # (bs, 128, 128, 128)
    down3 = downsample(256, 4)(down2)  # (bs, 64, 64, 256)
    down4 = downsample(512, 4)(down3)  # (bs, 32, 32, 512)
    down5 = downsample(512, 4)(down4)  # (bs, 16, 16, 512)
    down6 = downsample(512, 4)(down5)  # (bs, 8, 8, 512)

    zero_pad1 = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D()(down6)  # (bs, 10, 10, 512)
    conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
        1024, 4, strides=1, kernel_initializer=initializer, use_bias=False
    )(
        zero_pad1
    )  # (bs, 7, 7, 1024)

    batchnorm1 = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(conv)

    leaky_relu = tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU()(batchnorm1)

    zero_pad2 = tf.keras.layers.ZeroPadding2D()(leaky_relu)  # (bs, 9, 9, 1024)

    last = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 4, strides=1, kernel_initializer=initializer)(
        zero_pad2
    )  # (bs, 6, 6, 1)

    return tf.keras.Model(inputs=inp, outputs=last)

The conv2d and deconv2d functions are like below:
class BatchNorm(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, epsilon=1e-5, momentum=0.9, name=None):
        super(BatchNorm, self).__init__(name=name)
        self.epsilon = epsilon
        self.momentum = momentum
        self.batch_norm = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(
            epsilon=self.epsilon, momentum=self.momentum
        )

    def call(self, x, training=True):
        return self.batch_norm(x, training=training)


def conv2d(
    filters,
    kernel_size=5,
    stride=2,
    use_bias=True,
    activation="leaky_relu",
    name="conv2d",
    stddev=0.02,
):
    """Create a keras Sequential model to represent a convolution block with optional LeakyReLU."""
    layers = [
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(
            filters,
            kernel_size=(kernel_size, kernel_size),
            strides=(stride, stride),
            padding="SAME",
            use_bias=use_bias,
            kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=stddev),
            name=name,
        )
    ]
    if activation == "leaky_relu":
        layers.append(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2))

    return tf.keras.Sequential(layers, name=name)


def deconv2d(
    filters,
    kernel_size=5,
    stride=2,
    use_bias=True,
    apply_dropout=False,
    activation="relu",
    name="deconv2d",
    stddev=0.02,
):
    """Create a keras Sequential model to represent a deconvolution block with optional Dropout and ReLU."""
    layers = [
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2DTranspose(
            filters,
            kernel_size=(kernel_size, kernel_size),
            strides=(stride, stride),
            padding="SAME",
            use_bias=use_bias,
            kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=stddev),
            name=name,
        ),
        BatchNorm(),  # Assuming you have a BatchNorm class defined as per your previous code
    ]
    if apply_dropout:
        layers.append(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
    if activation == "relu":
        layers.append(tf.keras.layers.ReLU())

    return tf.keras.Sequential(layers, name=name)

And the downsample() function is like below:
def downsample(filters, size, apply_batchnorm=True, strides=2):
    """Utility function for downsampling an input."""
    initializer = tf.random_normal_initializer(0., 0.02)

    result = tf.keras.Sequential()
    result.add(
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters, size, strides=strides, padding='same',
                            kernel_initializer=initializer, use_bias=False))

    if apply_batchnorm:
        result.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())

    result.add(tf.keras.layers.LeakyReLU())

    return result

Finally, I have to mention that I have used the following optimizers:
LAMBDA = 1000 

generator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, beta_1=0.5)
discriminator_optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0004, beta_1=0.5)

def generator_loss(disc_generated_output, gen_output, target):
    gan_loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)(tf.ones_like(disc_generated_output), disc_generated_output)
    l1_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(target - gen_output))
    total_gen_loss = gan_loss + (LAMBDA * l1_loss)
    return total_gen_loss


def discriminator_loss(disc_real_output, disc_generated_output):
    real_loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)(tf.ones_like(disc_real_output), disc_real_output)
    generated_loss = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)(tf.zeros_like(disc_generated_output), disc_generated_output)
    total_disc_loss = real_loss + generated_loss
    return total_disc_loss

The problem is that when I run my fit() function and start the training loop no matter what the number of epochs is, I get Generator Loss of around 42 which I believe is too high while for Discriminator Loss I get a value like 0.5 at best case and after a specific point these values stay around the similar numbers and don't get changed a lot.
While the input and target images are not so different in my dataset, I don't get good visual results as well when I compare the predicted images with target images.
It might be useful to say that I visualize and save each 3 bands as a PNG image just like my train dataset.
Can I improve the structure of my generator/discriminator and as the result my overall model by changing the optimizers or so on?
It is also worth mentioning that there is not a big difference between my input and target images visually.
